# Any command-line tools for converting a series of photos at different angles to a smooth rotating video or 3D viewer?

Tags: command-line, video, 3d, image-processing

We have 36 photos of an item take 10 degrees apart, and I was wondering if there are any command-line tools that can take those images and interpolate them into a smooth video or 3D animation.

I know tools exist that can stitch together photos into a panorama, which is almost the same as I am looking for but rotates the camera on a central point, while in my scenario the item is the centre point and the camera was rotated around it.

One of the issues I have in finding a solution is that I don't know the term for this (i.e. the inverse of panorama).

Comment: Please edit your question to include your OS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing model capture, in that you probably want a 3D model (e.g. .3ds)  (which you want to feed into a suggestible renderer such as a 3D screensaver featuring teapots and named teapot,) and to use handbrake to capture that to 12 seconds of web-friendly (or 4k friendly h.265,) video.

I apologize for not knowing a project to use offhand.
Google search opines nicely toward using PyTorch to combine geometry capture, lighting hints and intuition...

Practically, for a one-off, get AutoDesk 123D Catch on a handy phone and have it capture the model, then pull the model off for use in Blender or teapot or furshader or walkthrough VR of some kind.

6 years ago Stanford had a sensation in make3D ( http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/ .)  Many HMI iterations later, surely there are better versions on sourceforge or via a proper hunt on github or among arXiv human-machine interfaces. Mine failed for now! Though "one-line image set to 3D converter" seems to be okay, and at least hauls up Selva3D.com to offer your command line some barely-size-checked http-get script action.

Current work (see author pages:) http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~hanbyulj/totalbody/
http://ccwu.me/vsfm/  Permits some motion across the images, but is in a GUI workflow. 
Jenn3d is one project on SourceForge that promises to generate a point cloud (no model needed?) and there are many that like to require a laser scan line in order to tell innies from shaded outies (along with the images,) but even http://ccwu.me/vsfm/ has to be unwound from the GUI to work.